# How to detect dirtyness when removing item from a store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a store with items retrieved from server. I would like to detect changes to alter UI accordingly.

I am able to detect dirty records (new, updated), but I don't know how to detect deletion, which I also need to handle...

An illustration of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/bBUB2/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way out: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/bBUB2/7/

This solution is less intrusive on models than the one suggested by jsworkman.
Not fully satisfying, but works as expected... :-/

Still interested in better implementation rather than workaround-flavoured solution!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Keep track of what posts were originally there so you can mark it as dirty if one is deleted.
2. Keep track of new posts, and if they are deleted then mark that part as clean.

Because of your call to each post's `isDirty` function, you are only checking if the current posts have been updated or created.  You basically need a snapshot of what posts exist when it is clean, and then you can compare if any of those have been deleted.

You can also keep a record of newly added posts.  That way when one is deleted you can check if it was added(add a `isNew` flag or something similar). Then when it is deleted you can check if it `isNew` and mark it clean again otherwise it makes it a dirty delete.

To do these things, you will need a function that checks for deletes as the first dirty check and then check the posts like you currently are.

Comment: Maybe I missed something (I would really like to have missed something...), but it seems to me this way is quite clumsy.

Comment: Well the other option would be to have a function that compares the new vs old.  Right now you are only checking the current records for updates(and if they are deleted you are not checking them at all)